# How to access quantityInStock on a dynamic page in Wix

Tags: velo

So I'm using Wix to create a ecommerce store, however the standard store isn't flexible enough for me.
I have a dynamic product page and I want to access product quantity in stock with code in order to show whether the product is in stock or not.

I fount this in the documentation ([Link](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.ProductPage.html))

```
$w('#myProductPage').getProduct()
  .then( (product) => {
    let productName = product.name;
    let productDescription = product.description;
    // see example product object below
  } )
  .catch( (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  } );
```

The only thing is that I don't know whats the page name with what i have to replace '#myProductPage'.
As far as I understand it I have to replace it with my slug product page name however I don't know where I could see it - it should be named products-2 but that doesn't work, it shows an error that the name is not a valid selector.

I haven't found basically any example codes for Wix Corvid and that's why I'm reaaally struggling with such a small thing.

Answer (score 1):

With $w(), you want to pass in the page element's ID -> $w('#elementID')

The element ID can be found in the property pane on the page. Select the page element, right click > View Properties. This will give you the ID you want to pass in to the function. Think of it like a document.getElementById() function replacement.